# store values from text file into map

Tags: java, hashmap

How do I read strings from a text file and store in a hashmap? 
File contains two columns.

File is like:

FirstName LastName
Pranay Suyash and so on...

Comment: please post what you have so far. if you don't have anything, search for tutorials and search this site for the keywords you put.

Comment: Please post a few lines from your actual input file. There may be a very, very trivial solution, but we need to see a small sample.

Comment: The actual input is as above only,ie, it contains a column having firstname then a space and the another column Secondname and corresponding values in multiple rows.

Comment: are you sure a HashMap is the correct data structure? FirstName is a very weak key. What do you expect to happen if you have two or more people with a first name of Pranay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("filename.txt"));

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            map.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Given input:

```
somekey somevalue
someotherkey someothervalue
```

this prints

```
{someotherkey=someothervalue, somekey=somevalue}
```

If your lines look differently, I either suggest you fetch `columns[0]` and `columns[1]` and do your string manipulation as needed, or, if you're comfortable with regular expressions, you could use `Pattern` / `Matcher` to match the line against a pattern and get the content from the capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

In the hash map if you want to map each row in the two columns you can make the first column value as the key and the second column as the value. But the keys should be unique in the Hashmap. If the first column values are unique you can go for the following approach

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put(firstColVal,secondColVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case

- your keys (first column) **don't** contain spaces and
- your columns are separated by either a `:`, a `=` or a white char (except newline)

then this may work:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new Properties();
((Properties) map).load(new FileReader("inputfile.txt"));
```

---

Just saw your sample input... You shouldn't put *that* data in a map, unless it is guaranteed that **all** firstnames are unique.

Otherwise this will happen:

```
 map.put("Homer", "Simpson");   // new key/value pair
 map.put("Bart", "Simpson");    // new key/value pair
 map.put("Homer", "Johnsson");  // value for "Homer" is replaced with "Johnsson"

 System.out.println(map.get("Homer"));  // guess what happens..
```

Comment: It is guaranteed that each firstname is different. What happens if the first column contains space? And if ever i encounter such a situation what do you suggest i need to do?

Comment: @Pranay - you need a clear way to separate the columns, either by defining a *Delimiter* (a `;`, a tab, a space, ...) or by defining a position (like *second column starts at position 20*). If *space* is your delimiter and you have multi word firstnames ("Homer Bart Simpson"), an algorithm can't decide, wether the second word ("Bart") belongs to the firstname or to the lastname.